# How does the terminal compile java programs when $CLASS_PATH is not set?

Tags: java, ubuntu, environment-variables

I read on several answers here,that the $CLASSPATH is used to help compile java programs by pointing it to location of necessary predefined classes and the program's .class file

i checked my $CLASSPATH's value and fount it to be null.This gives rise to my question.

if the $CLASSPATH variable is not set,how are we able to compile java programs from the terminal?

Suppose i have a java program **myclass**,which on compiling will create a  **myclass.class** file.(i use the terminal to compile and run the programs)

how is the terminal able to find the location of the **myclass.class** file..eventhough my $CLASSPATH variable is empty?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) is pretty clear on the subject: *The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH variable or the -cp command line switch overrides this value.*

Comment: So since the default value of a $CLASSPATH is ".",It searches the same directory as the programs and is able to execute it.Thanks,man